# React native bind class to something like window in web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Usually in my React projects I tend to have a class that is binded to window and rendered at root and it just renders children that are passed in functions. It's not really the way I liked doing it at first but when I have 6 different forms in 2 pages I started liking the use of it, and in some other cases like notifying the user or something.

```
import React from "react";

export class Modal extends React.Component<unknown, State> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentElement: null,
    };
    window.modalComponent = this;
  }
  public assignElement(element: JSX.Element) {
    this.setState({
      currentElement: element,
    });
  }
  public removeElement() {
    this.setState({
      currentElement: null,
    });
  }
  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.state.currentElement ? "modal-full" : "modal-hidden"}
      >
        {this.state.currentElement}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
type State = {
  currentElement: JSX.Element | null;
};
export function displayElementInModal(element: JSX.Element) {
  window.modalComponent.assignElement(element);
}
export function removeElementFromModal() {
  window.modalComponent.removeElement();
}
declare global {
  interface Window {
    modalComponent: Modal;
  }
}
```

This is the basic component that I then render in App.tsx

Now what is the equivalient of binding the class to window like in previous code like
 `window.modalComponent = this;` in constructor. But in React Native (Expo managed)